# Registration of different versions of same ActiveX

Tags: delphi, activex

I´m struggling with what is the best design for an ActiveX control in regards to its registration and reference.

One part of our software is based on ActiveX controls that are used on Internet Explorer and referenced by its GUID, and ActiveX control will make the connection to the server and will get the data (Live Images) from it.

The problem that I´m facing is that everytime that we update the server version we have to change the version of the ActiveX controls because there are usually new codes for client, so, the ActiveX of version 6.3 for example will not connect to a 6.4 server and must be updated

The thing is that, what is the best design to have different versions of the same ActiveX registered on the machine? Should I change the GUID of the ActiveX every new version???

I have searched a lot for this and couldn´t find anything satisfactory, and I can´t use the Registration-free COM because the ActiveX control is meant to be used inside Internet Explorer

Comment: Normally the approach would be that new versions of the server support old versions of the client. So you would not routinely compel the clients to upgrade. At some point you may choose to break back compat. But the pain should be less severe if you do that infrequently. Even so, why do users need multiple versions of the ActiveX installed? Are you breaking the interface to the ActiveX? Don't knew versions of the ActiveX still support the binary API from previous versions? If not, why not?

Comment: David, it is a bit complex because the client (ActiveX and Desktop) communicates to the server using a binary proprietary protocol, and usually we add new commands and new stuff to the protocol so as a rule, each new version we "break the compatibility" of the client and the server, so the clients (ActiveX or Desktop) must always be at the same version, it would be really hard to keep compatibility due to how much we change stuff

Clients need multiple versions when they need to access servers from different versions, this is not a problem for Desktop but I´m finding difficult to solve in IE

Comment: You should define new ActiveX interfaces for new protocol commands, while maintaining backwards compatibility with existing interfaces and existing commands. That allows older clients to continue using older versions (without actually requiring multiple versions be installed) and older commands against newer servers, and newer clients can use newer interfaces and newer commands if they are available. If a newer client wants to use a newer interface and it is not installed, fall back to something older, or fail the operation and prompt the user to upgrade.

Comment: Unless you are fundamentally changing the structure of the protocol itself every time, there is no need to break backwards compatibility whenever a new command is added. And if possible, design the protocol so the server can report its capabilities upon connect or by request, so that clients can discover which commands are allowed. Or at least make sure that unknown commands report a predictable result so newer clients talking to older servers can fail gracefully and not break.

Comment: What you are doing goes against how ActiveX is designed to be used.

Comment: Perhaps, you still can use Registration-free COM and place your ActiveX DLL side-by-side with your `Delphi` EXE. Registration-free COM is not specific to Internet Explorer. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) provides some examples for `VB6`, maybe you could try the same approach for `Delphi`.

Comment: Remy, I understand that it must have backward compatibility, but what if we HAVE to break the compatibility of the control in a specific scenario and need to have different versions of the control installed, what would be the best approach? I was thinking that changing the CLSID was the only way to achieve that...

Comment: I usually change the name of the Com dll..using the version that the interface is compatible with in the name...like MyDll63.dll... As Remy stated good COM practices say that you should support the interface that you implement.  If you can't do that then make sure to break the connection between your Client and Server and let the Client know gracefully that they are using an old version and need to upgrade.  Have the Server send the latest and greatest version of the interface that it supports, The client then checks to see if the new interface is supported, if not it knows to fail gracefully.

Comment: Hum, interesting but I´m not using COM controls, it is just 1 OCX file and yes, when the client (ActiveX control) connects to the server it checks if it is compatible, if it is not compatible, the client can download a new version and install, but since the GUID is the same, it will just overwrite old control, but the user might want to connect to a different system with a different version..
I checked that JAVA changes the plugin GUID every new version
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/version.html